# PHP multithreaded cURL alternative proposed, but is it good?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

Because PHP doesn't have multithreading capabilities I am trying to find a workaround to speed up a simple process.

The process is I am posting data to a webpage with various permutations in the post-data on each request. In a `foreach` loop I am checking each request response to see if a string exists using `strspos`. When it is found, it `break`s and returns the page. There are around 1000 requests, and it takes bout 1 minute to complete or longer.

As I don't want to use additional libraries, my idea was to exec standalone scripts passing each permutation of post data (say 1000 processes). Each process will only write to a file if the string is found. And on the main script I will run a loop checking if file exists, when it does find that the file exists, can read the file for the post data that was correct.

It seems sound in theory, but I wanted to check if this is a ridiculous solution for a problem that has much simpler solutions!

Thanks.

Comment: I'll stop youat the first phrase; yes it does: http://php.net/Thread

Comment: @ Joe, well if you didn't stop at first line you will see "As I don't want to use additional libraries" ;)

Comment: You said "because PHP doesn't have multithreading capabilities", and it does; as you say, the reason you want to hack around it is because you don't want to use additional libraries, nothing to do with PHP's support for anything.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using process control library

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php

I don't know if you have support for them installed

Comment: The OP clearly stated: _"As I don't want to use additional libraries,..."_ an answer suggesting a lib isn't quite what is being asked for

Comment: PCNTL is not an additional library; it's distributed with PHP.